how to authenticate websocket in spring boot
I have this spring boot app that I secured with jwt, the project contains some implementation of websocket but whenever I hit the localhost:8080 that supposed to open the html page for my websocket, I am having access denied even when I specified that the path for websocket should be permitted.I have 3 static pages for the websocket named index.html,main.css and main.js, I don't really know if I need to specify them in the security config also.
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(req->
                        req.requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**",
                                        "/v2/api-docs",
                                        "/v3/api-docs",
                                        "/v3/api-docs/**",
                                        "/swagger-resources",
                                        "/swagger-resources/**",
                                        "/ws/**",
                                        "/configuration/ui",
                                        "/configuration/security",
                                        "/swagger-ui/**",
                                        "/webjars/**",
                                        "/swagger-ui.html"
                                .permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/video/**").hasAuthority("MANAGER")
                                .requestMatchers("/user/**").hasAuthority("MANAGER")
                                .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(session ->session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
}


@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
                .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean configureMessageConverters(List<MessageConverter> messageConverters) {
        DefaultContentTypeResolver resolver = new DefaultContentTypeResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultMimeType(MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON);
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper());
        converter.setContentTypeResolver(resolver);
        messageConverters.add(converter);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/user");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user/{userId}/**");
    }
}


@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ChatController {

    private final SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;
    private final ChatMessageService chatMessageService;

    @MessageMapping("/chat")
    public void processMessage(@Payload ChatMessageDto chatMessageDto) throws DataNotFoundException {
        ChatMessage chatMessage = chatMessageService.saveMessage(chatMessageDto);
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(chatMessage.getRecipientId(),
                "/queue/messages",
                ChatNotification.builder()
                        .chatId(chatMessage.getChatId())
                        .senderId(chatMessage.getSenderId())
                        .recipientId(chatMessage.getRecipientId())
                        .content(chatMessage.getContent())
                        .build());
    }

    @PostMapping("/all/chats/for/user")
    public ResponseEntity<List<ChatMessage>> findAllChats(@RequestBody GetChatMessageDto chatMessageDto){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(chatMessageService.findChatMessages(chatMessageDto), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}


@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserInfoController {

    private final UserInfoService userInfoService;


    @MessageMapping("/user.addUser")
    @SendTo("/user/public")
    public UserInfo addUser(@Payload UserInfo userInfo){
        userInfoService.saveUser(userInfo);
        return userInfo;
    }

    @MessageMapping("/user.disconnectUser")
    @SendTo("/user/public")
    public UserInfo disconnectUser(@Payload UserInfo userInfo) throws DataNotFoundException {
        userInfoService.disconnect(userInfo);
        return userInfo;
    }

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public ResponseEntity<List<UserInfo>> getConnectedUsers(){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userInfoService.findConnectedUser(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/users/all")
    public ResponseEntity<List<UserInfo>> getAllRegisteredUsers(){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userInfoService.findAllRegisteredUser(),HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

